# Prevent zooming when clicking a link on Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm pretty good at clicking the link I want to click. Most of the time it magnifies and makes me tap again when the first tap was sufficiently centered. I want it to just assume I got close enough and go to the link closest to the center of the area I tapped. Is it possible?